# How to make Ubuntu Server fit into a VMware window?

Tags: command-line, server, vmware, interface, framebuffer

I installed Ubuntu Server edition in VMware 7.0.1. I am using latest version  of Ubuntu.
Ubuntu is not filling into complete VMware window. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Go through the menus to the Ubuntu server video preferences and increase the screen resolution to the same as your VMware window is. If you are using VMware full-screen, this is the same resolution as you have your monitor at.

If your Ubuntu server video resolutions don't go up that high in the preferences, you probably haven't given the virtual machine enough video ram. You can increase this in the VMware preferences for that virtual machine instance, but not while it is running, so you will need to turn off that VM to change the video ram settings.